# elasticsearch positional arguments not allowed

Tags: windows, elasticsearch

while trying to start elasticsearch (version 7.9) node, with the following command  :

```
D:\temp\elasticsearch-7.9.2>  .\bin\elasticsearch.bat -Ecluster.name=my_cluster -Enode.name=node_2 Epath.data=data
```

i got the error:

```
D:\temp\elasticsearch-7.9.2>.\bin\elasticsearch.bat -Ecluster.name=my_cluster -Enode.name=node_2 E node.path.data=data
future versions of Elasticsearch will require Java 11; your Java version from [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre] does not meet this requirement
future versions of Elasticsearch will require Java 11; your Java version from [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre] does not meet this requirement
Warning: with JDK 8 on Windows, Elasticsearch may be unable to derive correct
  ergonomic settings due to a JDK issue (JDK-8074459). Please use a newer
  version of Java.
Warning: MaxDirectMemorySize may have been miscalculated due to JDK-8074459.
  Please use a newer version of Java or set MaxDirectMemorySize explicitly.
Starts Elasticsearch

Option                Description
------                -----------
-E <KeyValuePair>     Configure a setting
-V, --version         Prints Elasticsearch version information and exits
-d, --daemonize       Starts Elasticsearch in the background
-h, --help            Show help
-p, --pidfile <Path>  Creates a pid file in the specified path on start
-q, --quiet           Turns off standard output/error streams logging in console
-s, --silent          Show minimal output
-v, --verbose         Show verbose output
ERROR: Positional arguments not allowed, found [E, node.path.data=data]
```

Answer (score 2):

i missed th dash - in front of the path parameter (i typed:   Epath.data=data  instead of  -Epath.data=data)

once this was addressed  the node started

```
D:\temp\elasticsearch-7.9.2>.\bin\elasticsearch.bat -Ecluster.name=my_cluster -Enode.name=node_2 -Epath.data=data
```